# log4j: Unrecognized element rollingPolicy

Tags: log4j, tomcat7

I have an app running on Tomcat 7.0.2 and using log4j for logging.
Shortly after tomcat start the following messages appear in catalina.out:

```
INFO: Initializing log4j from [file:///export0/home/tomcat/appconf/log4j.xml]
log4j:WARN Unrecognized element rollingPolicy
log4j:WARN Please set a rolling policy for the RollingFileAppender named 'PERFFILE'
log4j:WARN Unrecognized element rollingPolicy
log4j:WARN Please set a rolling policy for the RollingFileAppender named 'FILE'
```

and when my actual log messages should print, I see the following:

```
log4j:ERROR No output stream or file set for the appender named [FILE].
log4j:ERROR No output stream or file set for the appender named [PERFFILE].
```

These two appenders are defined like this:

```
 <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="Append" value="true" />
      <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/server.log" />
      <rollingPolicy class="com.myapp.logging.AgingTimeBasedRollingFilePolicy">
           <param name="fileNamePattern" value="${catalina.base}/logs/archive/server.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz" />
           <param name="keepFilesForDays" value="30" />
      </rollingPolicy> 
      <layout class="com.myapp.logging.jboss.WebappAwarePattern">
           <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601}{${server.localTimezone}} %p [%X{webapp}:%c{2}] %m%n" />
      </layout>
 </appender>

 <appender name="PERFFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/performance.log" />
    <rollingPolicy class="com.myapp.logging.AgingTimeBasedRollingFilePolicy">
        <param name="fileNamePattern" value="${catalina.base}/logs/archive/performance.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz" />
        <param name="keepFilesForDays" value="30" />
    </rollingPolicy>
    <layout class="com.myapp.logging.jboss.WebappAwarePattern">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601}{${server.localTimezone}} %p [%X{webapp}:%c{2}] %throwable{0} %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

I've been having a hard time trying to fugure out why this errors occur but got no result (probably my log4j.xml can not be parsed correctly)

So any ideas why this happens would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [the Appenders documentation page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender):

```
Parameter Name    Type               Description
policy            TriggeringPolicy   The policy to use to determine
                                     if a rollover should occur.
```

I think you should replace `rollingPolicy` with `policy`. This probably depends on whether you are using 2.0 or 1.2; I dont see `policy` in the 1.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you set the wrong class or your custom class for the **rollingPolicy class**  on your two appenders that maybe not exist or not recognize by log4j

```
 <rollingPolicy class="com.myapp.logging.AgingTimeBasedRollingFilePolicy">
```

So change both appenders class with:

```
<rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
```

that have been provided by  [apache-log4j-extras](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/apache-log4j-extras) jar